# 2014 Nissan Rogue throwing B142a after engine misfires

Tags: electrical, nissan, supplemental-restraint-system

My 2014 Nissan Rogue started having electrical issues, which I finally found was due to the VVT solenoids needing replaced. But even though the engine is firing correctly I am still getting an error from my airbags of B142a. Is it possible that the electrical issues FUBARed the airbag module? What would be my next steps to get this code fixed?

Comment: I think these are two separate problems. If I'm not mistaken, the airbag system is completely separate from all other electronics with its own self diagnostic airbag module. Even the airbag indicator is driven from the a/b module. Unless you have the wiring diagrams for your a/b system and/or service manuals, you're left second guessing where to start diagnosing and troubleshooting. There are many sensors to the a/b system.